# android - relative layout - put object on top of each other

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to put one object on top of another?

I have a background image (ImageView) on top of that background I want to put a face (ImageView) and another image that is a speech bubble that comes out of the face (ImageView). So both the face and the speech bubble go on top of the background ImageView.

On top of the speech bubble I want to put TextView.

How can I do such thing?

Thanks

Comment: Consider using FrameLayout instead http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this if you properly order your child views within the `RelativeLayout`. A `RelativeLayout` draws child views in the order in which they appear in the XML. That means the last item in the XML is the last item drawn and as a result will be drawn on top of anything else in the same place. By controlling the order of your child views, putting what you want on top further down in the XML, you should be able order your items so they appear as you like.

Answer (score 3):

Create a `Relativelayout` as parent and place the your `ImageView` and `TextView` as center to parent , i.e., `android:layout_centerInParent= "true"`

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@color/white">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@color/Red"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:src="@color/Blue"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

<TextView
    android:text="HELLO"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: "Invalid lauout param"

Comment: this is what is says when I put that property on the ImageView

Comment: Is your parent layout relative. First Just copy this complete layout and set for an activity. See if it works. Then you can include in your other layouts